# TestNG + Selenium + Maven + Jenkins ! Not generating testNG reports in the jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, jenkins

I have added testNG dependency and all other required dependencies in pom.xml to create the TestNG report.
In Jenkins I have added the TestNG plugin to publish the TestNG report and set the pattern as mention below. But testNG report is not getting generated in jenkins.

Even when i execute the code from the jenkins then Testng reprot is not generated, but when i run the code from the Eclipsse the Testng Report is generated

Please share some inputs on how to resolve this issue:

"testng-results.xml" file is not available in workspace.

[image]

Note: I am using Jenkins jenkins-2.142 in Windows 10.